# Tcl: Getting all variables defined under a namespace

Tags: namespaces, tcl

Is there any robust mechanism for getting all variables that are declared using the "variable" keyword under a given namespace?

For example, consider the following code:

```
namespace eval MyNamespace {
    variable showThisVar1
    set dontShowThisVar1 1
    proc MyProc { } { 
        variable showThisVar2
        set dontShowThisVar2 1            
    }  
}
```

I am looking for a robust way to get showThisVar1 and showThisVar2, which have been declared as variables in the namespace MyNamespace. The result of the query should not return dontShowThisVar1 and dontShowThisVar2.

Comment: Just wondering why you asked this question.   What's the purpose of knowing which variables use the `variable` command versus the `set` command?

Comment: My actual purpose is to allow a save/load mechanism in a tcl-based tool that I have. The initial motivation for finding the variables is because basically all the "important" data is being saved in namespace variables in this tool, so those are the variables I really need to be able to locate for saving purposes.
However I realize I don't really need this differentiation, and a plain use of [info vars] would probably suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `info vars` and `info exists`.

After running your code, as is, you can use `info vars` to get all the variables in MyNamespace.

```
> info vars MyNamespace::*

::MyNamespace::dontShowThisVar1 
::MyNamespace::showThisVar1
```

First note that `showThisVar2` is not listed.  This is because MyNamespace::MyProc has not been called.

```
> MyNamespace::MyProc
> info vars MyNamespace::*

::MyNamespace::showThisVar2
::MyNamespace::dontShowThisVar1
::MyNamespace::showThisVar1
```

After calling the proc, `MyNamespace::showThisVar2` has been declared in the namespace.   `dontShowThisVar2` doesn't appear in the list from `info vars`, because it is scoped to the proc.

To only show variables which were declared with the `variable` command, but not actually set to a value, you could check with `info exists`:

```
foreach var [info vars MyNamespace::*] {
     if {![info exists $var]} {
         puts $var
     }
}

::MyNamespace::showThisVar2
::MyNamespace::showThisVar1
```

Until answering your question, I didn't realize that a variable could be returned with `info vars` but not return a 1 with `info exists`.

Comment: `variable` can put variables in a weird half-set state like that, which matters for name resolution purposes. That it matters at all is really horrible, and has caught out *many* experienced Tcl programmers.

Comment: Both  *variable showThisVar1* and *set dontShowThisVar1 1* are declared in very bad style. 1st is explained by Donal, but 2nd should be better *variable dontShowThisVar1 1*.

Comment: Probably how to find those bad variables like *showThisVar1* and *dontShowThisVar1* was the reason of this question.

Comment: @AlexP can you please clarify what that is a very bad style?
About showThisVar1 - I understand the half-state mentioned but why is it so bad that it is declared as a variable and then several rows later is assigned to an actual value (not shown in the original code above)?

Comment: See section "Gotcha: Variable Resolution" in https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/set - that's about dontShowThisVar1. About showThisVar1 see answers already done.

Comment: The *variable* command is rather crafty, so you should take simple rules for its usage. It's used in *namespace eval* in one form (where it's very recommended to be initialized at worst as *variable var1 {} [var2 {} ...]* ), while in *proc* in another form - just as a reference to a namespace variable, i.e. without any initialization and without multiple vars in one *variable*. There are other issues with *variable*, still the mentioned ones are common.

Comment: Well, *several rows later* can turn into much rows in course of time. Anyhow, those rows may look strange in 2-3 month later, if you aren't going to ignore the maintenance of the code.